# JavaFX8 external canvas in a pane

Tags: html, canvas, javafx

My application calls for a canvas to be rendered externally. Imagine a BorderPane where the centre pane is a canvas. This canvas needs to be rendered from a combination of an external .html, a .js and a .css file. My JavaFX app will write these files as a result of what the user chooses in the left pane, right pane etc. of the BorderPane. In other words, much like a paint program, the user can create a design.

Then my thoughts were to execute a browser in the centre pane and use something like liveReload to monitor the underlying file system. That works, but I have no control over the browser window e.g. Chrome in kiosk mode expands to the screen and not to the centre pane.
Then I looked at external renderers such as Mozilla XUL, but that seems to be close to deprecation.

The reason for needing this, is that the final files (html, js and css) will be rendered in kiosk mode by a totally separate system that does not support JavaFX, but does support HTML canvas.

Should I forget about JavaFX alltogether and write the whole app in some other language/system/framework or can anyone throw some ideas into the pot?

Comment: Can't you just use a [`WebView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) in the center of the `BorderPane`? Maybe I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I looked at WebView some time ago and after some tests decided that JavaFX HTML5 canvas was only partially supported (gradients etc.) Just checked the Oracle docs again and they claim full HTML5 support, so I'll do some testing again and check it out. Maybe now it's an option. Thanks James.